# How to get md5 hash of concatenated (merged) string?

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5

Suppose I have `md5(m1)` and `m2`. How can I calculate `md5(m1+m2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of an MD5 digest is simply the concatenation of the 4x 32bit integers that make up its internal state, so it is possible to derive the internal state from the hash. However before the main hashing loop is run, there is an initial pre-processing stage which pads the original message and incorporates the message length, and as a result you can't calculate `md5(m1+m2)` from `md5(m1)` and `m2`.

You should be able to calculate `md5(pad(m1)+m2)` from `md5(m1)` and `m2`. Where `pad(m1)` is the result of running MD5's pre-processing stage on `m1`, though that may not be particularly useful.

Comment: However this is pretty useful in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You... can't.  `md5` is not a composable function in that sense.

If you are trying to do password salting, then the approach would be `md5(md5(m1) + m2)`.

Comment: No, the question is not about salting. I want to find out if md5 digest finalization is reversible or not.

Comment: MD5 is a hash function and so, like all hash functions, is designed to be irreversible.  If you need a reversible function then look at using an encryption function, which will be designed to be reversible.

Comment: Please check the question. I'm not trying to _reverse_ hash. I'm trying to calculate one hash using knowledge of another hash and message.